# How can I wrap lines in Google Maps Autocomplete input

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps

I want to make it so Google Maps Autocomplete lines wrap into a second or possibly a third line to show full suggestion instead of truncating the address with [...].

Screenshot attached of what it's doing now:

[image]

Here's the code I have so far on the CSS. Most of is it just basic formatting but I've tried mixing overflow, word-break, etc...

```
// Google Maps Autocomplete
.pac-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 26.5%!important;
}
.pac-item {
    height: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    font-size: .775rem;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to set `text-overflow: unset`. It helps if you first inspect the element(s) in question using your browser's developer tools to see what CSS properties you need to reverse.

Comment: right click on the text box, and inspect the element. Then copy and post the full css code for that element. The css you posted doesnt have (text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;) which gives you dot dot dot in the 1st place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following CSS and you should be good to go. No need to change other google maps default CSS properties.

```
.pac-item{
  white-space:pre-line;
}
```

This will disable the ellipsis property and all the suggestion text will be shown.

Place this in your CSS file and it should work. If it doesn't work, try experiment placing the CSS in head or just before the body tag closing.

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7fqctj16/1/)